# How to extract cell format (bold, italic, color, etc.) containing rich text using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl, richtext

I would like to extract font of a cell containing rich text ,which means in same cell there is a text in bold and another text in italic [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNAJi.png), I worked with openpyxl and I tried with bellow code but I got an incorrect result: False

```
import openpyxl
path="doc.xlsx"
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = 5, column = 5)
print(cell_obj.font.bold)
```

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rich_text.html

Comment: thanks , but  I want to extract the containing of cell from excel  with color of text and font not to edit in excel , do you have in idea about that?

Comment: https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/io/xlsx_cells is an option. https://samukweku.github.io/data-wrangling-blog/notebooks/Meaningful-Formats.html has some examples

Comment: thanks but my  request is about  a cell containing many formats not only once, for example in same cell there is a text in italic and a text not in italic.

Comment: Have you tried [`load_workbook(..., rich_text=True)`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.reader.excel.html#openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook)? Then `type(cell.value) is CellRichText`.

Comment: Also since the rich text is an application of formatting to the value of the cell you'll need to look at the CellRichText Textblock makeup of the value, i.e. `cell_obj.value` not `cell_obj.font.bold`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to the comment
A textblock may be a whole word, two or more words or part of the word depending on where the font changes exist. Its also possible you might see the space character [between words] as a separate textblock if the space inherits the default font and not the style of the previous or next word.

For example, given the following text in the cell
[image]
we would expect 3 textblocks, one for each word.

To obtain the font details you might want to loop the text blocks using a for loop and print out the font style for each text block as shown;

In the example code  Either 'b' or 'bold' can be used to access the textblock bold state;
e.g. 
`font_style.b`
and 
`font_style.bold`
return the status of bolding in the text block. The same goes for italic where either `.i` or `.italic` can be used and for underline, `.u` or `.underline` can be used.

```
import openpyxl


path="foo.xlsx"
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, rich_text=True)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row=1, column=1)

for textblock_item in cell_obj.value:
    ### Check the textblock_item is an Openpyxl RichText TextBlock
    print(f"textblock_item type: '{type(textblock_item)}'")
    ### Type should be 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock'     

    ### Either of the following two lines should print the actual text in the block
    print(f"Block of text: '{textblock_item.text}'")
    print(f"Block of text: '{textblock_item}'")

    font_style = textblock_item.font
    print(f"Font Enhancements; Bold: {font_style.b}, "  
          f"Italic: {font_style.italic}, "
          f"Underline: {font_style.underline}")
    print(f"Font Size: {font_style.size}")
    print(f"Font family: {font_style.rFont}")
    if font_style.color is not None:
        if isinstance(font_style.color.index, str):
            print(f"Font Colour: {font_style.color.rgb}")
        else:
            print(f"Font Colour: Theme {font_style.color.theme}, Tint: {font_style.color.tint}")
    else:
        print(f"Font Colour: None")

    print("-----------------------------------\n")
```

and the output would be

```
Block of text: 'bold '
Font Enhancements; Bold: True, Italic: False, Underline: None
Font Size: 10.0
Font family: Calibri
Font Colour: FF00FF00
-----------------------------------

Block of text: 'itallic '
Font Enhancements; Bold: False, Italic: True, Underline: None
Font Size: 11.0
Font family: Arial
Font Colour: FFFF0000
-----------------------------------

Block of text: 'underline '
Font Enhancements; Bold: False, Italic: False, Underline: single
Font Size: 12.0
Font family: Verdana
Font Colour: FF0000FF
-----------------------------------
```

You can see the trailing spaces for each word is included in the word block but it may be separate as mentioned so you could include a check for that in the loop if its a problem.

As mentioned each block separates the font styles so if in the same example the first word 'bold' had the 'l' only underlined (no other font changes) this would change that textblock into three separate blocks made up of the characters in the word. 
Example

[image]

```
Block of text: 'bo'
Font Enhancements; Bold: True, Italic: False, Underline: None
Font Size: 10.0
Font family: Calibri
Font Colour: FF00FF00
-----------------------------------

Block of text: 'l'
Font Enhancements; Bold: True, Italic: False, Underline: single
Font Size: 10.0
Font family: Calibri
Font Colour: FF00FF00
-----------------------------------

Block of text: 'd '
Font Enhancements; Bold: True, Italic: False, Underline: None
Font Size: 10.0
Font family: Calibri
Font Colour: FF00FF00
-----------------------------------

... with the rest of the words as shown previously.
```

Comment: thanks ,Yes exactly what I want but when I execute the code an error message is displayed,    print(f"Block of text: '{textblock_item.text}'")
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: ***Double check you have `rich_text=True` set** Otherwise It appears to be a textblock that is not a string. We expect all `textblock_item` to be a *TextBlock* object and have the attribute 'text' which is the Text of that particular block being checked. Anyway the **.text** attribute is default, you can try changing that line to `print(f"Block of text: '{textblock_item}'"` or `print(f"Block of text: '{type(textblock_item)}'"` and make sure its type is *openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock*.

Comment: It didn't worked with me can you please correct in the code?

Comment: I've updated the code, the first line in the loop checks what 'type' `textblock_item` is. If this is not 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock' then you are not reading textblocks from the cell's value. If the type is 'str' then the cell is not rich text or not being read as rich text. If this is the case and you're sure the cell has rich text, then as mentioned previously, ensure that `rich_text=True` i,e, `openpyxl.load_workbook(path, rich_text=True)`